# How many linear subpsaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For some reason this question doesn’t seem to have the answer I’d expect. If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, there exists a basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$. Shouldn’t there just $2^n$ possible subspaces of $V$, and $\binom{n}{k}$ subspaces of dimension $k$?

Comment: $V$ is not the set $\lbrace v_1, ..., v_n \rbrace$.

Comment: How many lines through the origin are there in $\mathbb R^2$?  Each of those is a linear subspace.

Comment: How many one dimensional subspaces are there? Does it depend on how many elements are in the field?

Comment: "If V is an n-dimensional vector space over a field F, there exists a basis {v1,...,vn}" is a statement about the vector space V.  It says nothing about how many subspaces V has.